# Окрытие разных приложений в одном решении WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

У меня есть проект в visual studio имя которого WpfApp1(solution) В этом же решении я создал другое приложение под названием WpfApp2. Как я могу открыть окно приложения WpfApp2 из WpfApp1 и будет ли оно открываться при публикации?

Comment: Вы делаете что-то странное, что-то, что в обычных сценариях не делают. Другие окна в основном проекте, это MDI, но это не другое приложение, а все еще одно цельное, с его отдельными компонентами. Если речь про то, чтоб использовать компоненты одного проекта (например стили, классы, ресурсы) в другом, то это без проблем, делайте, достаточно лишь подключить зависимость. Но окно другого приложения в своем проекте... Это очень странная задумка...

Comment: если это нужно только для отладки - правой кнопкой на решении >> Set as Startup project

Answer (score 0):

Немного неясно, какова цель.
Можно запустить второе приложение как exe, если оно уже скомпилировано.
Для этого используется класс Process.

```
using System.Diagnostics; 
    ...
    Process.Start("Path to exe");
```

Или вы можете запустить два проекта непосредственно из Visual studio
, как описано [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2022)